# Add a text above an image using mudbalzor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, mudblazor

I need to implement this kind of view using mudblazor image components:

[image: I need to show the images with its titles like this]

I got the images correct, but how can I add text on top of the image like in the picture above? Here is my code:

```
<MudGrid>

u/foreach (var item in tabscatitm)
{
  <MudItem xs="3" >

    <MudImage Src=@item.ItemImageUrl Height="120" Width="120" u/onclick="ItemClick" 
      Class="rounded-lg"Style="border:thin;border-color:darkgray;border-radius:10px"/>

    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@item.ItemName</MudText>

    <MudText Typo="Typo.body2">@item.ItemShortName</MudText>

  </MudItem>
}

</MudGrid>
```

Comment: One way would be to have another grid in your cell that splits your text into a top row and the image into a bottom row inside your current cell. Another could be to use css classes that will force the image to the bottom and the test to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

#### CustomImage.razor

```cs
<div style="position: relative; cursor: pointer" @onclick="@this.Clicked">

  @* the image *@
  <MudImage Src="@this.Src" Alt="@this.Alt"/>

  @* A transparent background for the text *@
  <MudPaper
    Elevation="0"
    Class="rounded-0"
    Style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 25px; width: 100vw; opacity: 0.6">

    @* Hack: the text is needed to give the transparent part the proper height, but will also display the text in 0.6 transparency *@
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h4">@this.Name</MudText>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@this.ShortName</MudText>
  </MudPaper>

  @* The text (in black) *@
  <span style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; padding: 25px; width: 100vw; color: black">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h4">@this.Name</MudText>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6">@this.ShortName</MudText>
  </span>

</div>

@code {

  [Parameter]
  public string Src { get; set; } = default!;

  [Parameter]
  public string Alt { get; set; } = string.Empty;

  [Parameter]
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!;

  [Parameter]
  public string ShortName { get; set; } = default!;

  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }

  private async Task Clicked()
  {
    await this.OnClick.InvokeAsync();
  }
}
```

If used like this:

```cs
<MudGrid>
  @foreach (var item in this.items)
  {
    <MudItem md="6">
      <CustomImage
        Src="@item.Src"
        Name="@item.Name"
        ShortName="@item.ShortName"
        OnClick="@(() => this.Click(item))"/>
    </MudItem>
  }
</MudGrid>

@code {
  private readonly List<Item> items = new()
  {
    new Item { Name = "A tasty burger", ShortName = "Some more text or a price...", Src = "images/hamburger.jpg" },
    new Item { Name = "Another burger", ShortName = "...", Src = "images/hamburger.jpg" }
  };

  private void Click(Item item)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"Clicked {item.Name}");
  }
}
```

The result will be:

[image]

Note the comment about the hack: my CSS knowledge is rather limited, but I'm sure some colleague of yours can help with that. This is just a quick demo for you to get started.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. that is working perfectly. And also I need to know, how can I call a method when clicking this component. Can I use @onclick?

Comment: You're welcome @DanulHiviVihan. I also updated the demo so that you can click the `CustomImage` component.